# Functional equation (is there a polynomial or holomorphic solution?)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, polynomials, functional-equations

I've played around with the functional equation $p(z^2+1)=p(z)^2$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Is there a non constant polynomial or holomorphic solution? Can we say anything about uniqueness? If've found a real solution which converges on all real numbers and was interested if I could extend it. The solution was $f(x):=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)^{\frac{1}{2^n}} $ where $f(x):=f_1(x)=x^2+1$ and $f_n=f^{\circ n}$. I think I proved that this solution converges uniformly and is differentiable. I'd appreciate any ideas or help!

Comment: I've considered that if we have two functions $\alpha,\beta$ that satisfy this equation and they take on the same value for some complex number $z$ then they are also the same on the orbit of $z$ under $f$ which means $\alpha(f_n(z))=\beta(f_n(z))$ for all $n$

Comment: A generalized result of this you'll find in Milnor, Dynamics in One Complex Variable, Theorem 8.2. Basically you are solving a Schröder-equation.